# Lock or disable connections to Postgres while performing maintenance

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, maintenance, connections

I never have this issue with MySQL, but PostgreSQL is *always* a pain when trying to do any kind of maintenance.

I am trying to truncate and load new data into databases on a PostgreSQL server, but there are usually active connections, and this messes up things. There is also one particular database I need to drop and create, and current active doesn't allow me to drop it.

All these are setup in a script that should run. My issue is active connections is killing me and not letting the script work.

Do I lock connections to the DB or block connections? How do I do this? Not as familiar with PostgreSQL as I am with MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can set connection limit for role:

```
ALTER ROLE x SET CONNECTION LIMIT 0;
```

or for databases:

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET CONNECTION LIMIT 0;
```

After your maintenance chores are done, reset your limit to its previous value such as `-1` for unlimited connections.

Comment: Note: you risk leaving the database inaccessible if the automated system that runs these commands fails.

Comment: If this happens, how to fix it? Just restart PostgreSQL?

Comment: Just do not do it for admin roles